# Зачем увеличивать размер диска в облаке для повышения производительность?

Tags: производительность, google-cloud

Всем привет!

Речь идет о Google Cloud.

Не могу понять зачем увеличивать объем диска, чтобы увеличить производительность (скорость передачи).
Точнее понимаю, но не до конца.
Если диски не локальные, то данные передаются по сети между ВМ и диском.

Может кто-то объяснить простыми понятными словами, зачем нам увеличивать объем диска с 500Гб до 1Тб?
Как это влияет на скорость передачи/чтения/записи?

Если не трудно, можно какой-то пример совсем простой разобрать по полкам?

Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том что в google cloud (как и в AWS) максимальная скорость обмена с диском исскуственно ограничена:

> Performance scales linearly until it reaches either the limits of the disk or the limits of the instance to which the disk is attached. Limits of the instance to which the disk is attached are based on the machine type and the number of vCPUs on the instance.

[Вот](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance#cpu_count_size) таблица с количеством операций ввода-вывода за секунду:

[image: лимиты скорости операций ввода-вывода]

Как видите, эта максимальная скорость тем выше, чем больше объем диска. Именно поэтому вам как пользователю, чтобы получить выше скорость, нужно купить диск большего объема.

Это никак не связано с технологией, это чистый маркетинг.

Answer (score -1):

Скорость передачи данных, то что вы называете "производительностью диска" зависит исключительно от типа диска и имеет связь обратную описанной вами. Если речь идет о скорости обмена информации между диском и ВМ - размер диска вообще не имеет никакого значения.

Если говорить про Google Cloud, раз уж вы используете их сервис на платной основе, то для каждой из услуг у них есть калькулятор: https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator